# Phonegap + head.js on iOS, won't work?

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, head.js

I'm using Phonegap 2.1.0 on iOS. In my main.html-file I'm loading some html using jQuery.

However, one of the html-files I'm loading has its own Javascript that loads other files, in the same way ($.ajax etc.). Phonegap in Android loads these files and executes the Javascript in them, but iOS does not.

Example:
index.html:

```
<...>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(document).on('pageinit', function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'some.url',
          success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
            $("#some-div").html(data);
          },
          error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {}
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</...>
```

some.url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  head.js(
    "config-file.js",

    function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: PATH + 'some-other.url', // PATH? see below
        success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
          $("#some-div").html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {}
      });
    });
</script>
```

config-file.js:
    var PATH = 'mypath';

some-other.url:
    fails to load in iOS

All loaded files are served from the same domain.

Again, the code above works in Android. Any ideas why iOS fails to do this, and how to solve it? Is it head.js? (0.9.6)

Comment: head.js works in the index.html-file. But it doesn't seem to work in loaded script. Tried to use a function in index.html: `var headLoad = function() { head.js(arguments); };` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Both head.js and jquery's $.ajax don't fetch files from externally loaded script, in iOS. As mentioned, both do in Android. What am I forgetting in Xcode?

Comment: If I run the app within Safari (modified index.html, without cordova.js), everything works just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery Mobile, which depends on jQuery anyways, why not just use jQuery to do the file loading ?

```
$.getScript('path')
   .done(function(){
       ...
});
```

Otherwise you could also give HeadJS v0.99 a try to see if it fixes your issues.

Comment: Also be sure to use the latest jQuery version, some older versions (pre 1.7 something i think) had problems with local files.